# Source code of an Android platform API level

Tags: android

Suppose, I've installed a new API level, say 18, and want to look at the code of the package responsible for SMS messaging at this level. I have two questions:

- Is there a method to do this right in Android Studio?
- Where are the sources in my OS X file system (to look at it from console)?

Comment: What does "the code of the package responsible for SMS messaging" mean? Do you mean `SmsManager` in the Android SDK? Do you mean the AOSP app that is an SMS client? Do you mean the core OS bits that work with the radios to actually send the messages? Do you mean something else?

Comment: Well, I think `SmsManager` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, you can download the SDK sources via the SDK Manager, see the "Sources for Android SDK" entry for the API level. The SDK source code will be in `$ANDROID_SDK/sources`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have installed the Android SDK. I have not bothered with examining the source in Android Studio, though I would assume that it is possible, via the solution in Eagle11's answer or something else. Most of the time, I use plugins for Firefox and Chromium that add "view source" links in the JavaDocs, linking to the online repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a class in Android Studio, you can right click, and Go To Declaration. Then from that class file you can right click on the name of the file in the tab at the top, and Copy Path. That should show you right where the file is located.

For me SmsManager ends up being - /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-22/android/telephony/SmsManager.java